# HTML To Fit an image only in specific resolution

Tags: html

I want to display an image (It can be of any size) only in a table of 1280 x 800 Resolution it will not display on other screens.

Now I'm using an `<img>` element inside the body, and if the image is small, it doesn't fill the screen and if the image is big, it display it out off the screen.

So the html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mapa</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/libs/qimessaging/1.0/qimessaging.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/senaletica.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="mapa" alt="mapa" src="">
  </body>
</html>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    var session = new QiSession();

    session.service("ALMemory").done(function (ALMemory) {
        ALMemory.subscriber("PepperQiMessaging/totablet").done(function(subscriber) {
            subscriber.signal.connect(toTabletHandler);
        });
    });

    function toTabletHandler(value) {
        var imgMap = $('#mapa');

        imgMap.attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + value);
        imgMap.width($('window').width());
        imgMap.height($('window').height());
    }
});
```

I don't use any CSS at the moment.

Comment: You have to use css For this purpose to handle the image width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` is an actual javascript entity and should not be quoted, which then makes it a string. Removing the quotes from `'window'` will solve your problem.

See Below Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    function toTabletHandler(value) {
        var imgMap = $('#mapa');

        imgMap.attr('src', 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSd8cAJmOsrWimMAMpTAFOPURbw4q7uDKKxau1nimZ4V-usMb0w');
        imgMap.width($(window).width());
        imgMap.height($(window).height());
    }
    toTabletHandler(5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <img id="mapa" alt="mapa" src="">
  </body>
```

Comment: How does this address the question of only displaying at a specific screen size/resolution? There is no real difference between this and the original post. Perhaps clarify what you have done.

Comment: @JonP it has removed the quotes of `window` in the jQuery functions of `width` and `height`, and without quotes it works because in JS `window` is an existing variable that refers to the window of the device. With quotes it is looking for a `<window>` html tag that it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's always worth giving a summary of your changes in your answer, particularly with something as subtle as removing quotes.